# abrir un div oculto al hacer click en un enlacede otra pagina

Tags: jquery

Voy a intentar explicar lo que necesito, he encontrado algunas cosillas parecidas pero no iguales y no me funciona.

Al hacer click en un boton o enlace quiero que abra otra pagina .html y muestre
un div oculto de esta.

ejemplo:

PAGINAPRINCIPAL.HTML

```
<div class="title">PARIS
<a id="detalhes" href="ofertas.html">DETALHES</a></div>
```

============================================================

PAGINASECUNDARIA.HTML (PAGINA DONDE AI DIV OCULTOS)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/HIDDEN.css">
#detalhes1, 
#detalhes2,
#detalhes3,
#detalhes4,
#detalhes5,
#detalhes6,
#detalhes7,
#detalhes8
{
    display: none;
}

<div class="block2" id="detalhes1" >
                        <img src="images/page2_img1.jpg" alt="" class="img_inner fleft">
                        <div class="extra_wrapper">
                            <div class="text1 col1"><a>Barcelona</a></div>
                            <p>Cras facilisis, nulla vel viverra auctor, leo gna sodales felis, quis malesuada nibh odio ut velit. Proin pharetra luctus diam, a celerisque eros convallis accumsan. </p>Maecenas vehicula egestas venenatis. Duis massa elit, auctor non pellentesque vel
                            <br>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block2" id="detalhes2" >
                        <img src="images/page2_img2.jpg" alt="" class="img_inner fleft">
                        <div class="extra_wrapper">
                            <div class="text1 col1"><a>Barcelona</a></div>
                            <p>Cras facilisis, nulla vel viverra auctor, leo gna sodales felis, quis malesuada nibh odio ut velit. Proin pharetra luctus diam, a celerisque eros convallis accumsan. </p>Maecenas vehicula egestas venenatis. Duis massa elit, auctor non pellentesque vel
                            <br>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block2" id="detalhes3" >
                        <img src="images/page2_img3.jpg" alt="" class="img_inner fleft">
<div class="extra_wrapper">
<div class="text1 col1"><a>Barcelona</a></div>
<p>Cras facilisis, nulla vel viverra auctor, leo gna sodales felis, quis malesuada nibh odio ut velit. Proin pharetra luctus diam, a celerisque eros convallis accumsan. </p>Maecenas vehicula egestas venenatis. Duis massa elit, auctor non pellentesque vel
                            <br>

                        </div>
```

Comment: Perdón, pero cuál seria la idea de ocultar divs si de todas formas no se ven xq no está abierta la pagina??

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el problema es que hay parte de la nueva página que solo querés mostrar cuando se llega a la misma desde una página en particular (la primera página de tu ejemplo).

Para resolverlo podés enviar un parametro al servidor junto con el request indicando cual es la página de origen.

Cuando el servidor recibe el request se fija si viene el parametro, y si es así, si tiene el valor esperado.

Si el valor es el esperado, entonces o directamente baja el html mostrando esa parte (la escondida) del documento, o setea una variable javascript en el documento, para que una vez cargada la página, usando javascript se muestre la parte escondida.

El parámetro puede mandarse com query en un GET

`http://www.example.com/paginadestino.html?orgien=mi_primera_pagina`

Haciendo un POST de un formulario, colocando la variable en un `input hidden`

```
<form method="POST" target="http://www.example.com/paginadestino.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="orgien" value="mi_primera_pagina"/>
  <input type"submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Si la página es de tu mismo sitio, también podrias setear el parámetro como una cookie.
Pero me parece que es más factible usar uno de los métodos anteriores.

Nota: Vale de más decir que cualquier información que esté escondida en un html, es solo eso, está escondida pero está ahí para cualquiera que tenga tiempo y ganas de buscarla.